# What is a correct origin path of nginx docker container?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

New to docker and docker-compose, and trying to get a set of Angular frontend, Spring boot backend and Mysql database containers to work.

I am able to get backend and database to talk to each other (my backend spring boot app connects properly to the database ), but my angular frontend is getting blocked by CORS.

Seems I am doing something wrong when trying to enable it in spring security config.

In my previous, non-docker setup, when running everything on localhost, this did the trick:

```
 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**",configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Now, in docker environment this doesnt work, the angular app is not running on ng serve localhost:4200 anymore.

So i experimented around, trying to figure out where the request is coming from, using the container name as a source with no joy. Next step was to allow all origins, like this:

```
configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
```

This compiles, but is wrong again, it didnt help. And on top of that, when I switch back to non-docker localhost environment, I am getting the same error again, until I specifically set the origin back to http://localhost:4200

This means I failed to set my spring security cors configuration to allow all origins.

Two questions:

- how to allow all origins properly in spring boot security config?
- my container name is "frontend", connected to bridge network, built on image nginx:stable-alpine-slim serving my angular app, with ports: - 80:80    What is the origin my requets to backend come from, inside the docker bridge network?

Comment: Have you tried `addAllowedOriginPattern("*")`?

Comment: @Woodchuck Thank you very much, that did it, it is now open properly. For question 2, I slept on it and realized my requests to backend will come from browsers, the outside world, not from inside the nginx container on the bridge network, so need to open my backend port as well. Will test, and if that proves true, will post a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

Proper(working) way to open spring security backend(in my implementation) to all CORS origins is

```
addAllowedOriginPattern("*")
```

courtesy of Woodchucks comment. Thanks again.

Question 2:

Angular application is running in the browser, not in the docker container. So all requests it is making to backend come from the browser, and not over docker bridge VPN. Backend port thus must be open to the outside world as well, not only to other containers over bridge network.

The working configuration of the setup is both nginx and backend containers are opened to the outside. Only backend and database containers are communicating via docker bridge network.